# How to make an optional tkinter GUI?

Tags: python, function, user-interface, tkinter, python-turtle

I have a tkinter GUI code that executes different functions which are mapped to different buttons/widgets, I want to give users the option of choosing to open the GUI window or directly execute from the command line.

I tried keeping mainloop() inside an optional switch like:

```py
if gui == "1":
    root.mainloop()
else:
    #command mode
    # call required functions here using user switches.
```

Is this the correct way of doing this? this is working when i tried in linux system.

Comment: you would have to keep ALL GUI in `if` - starting at `root = tk.Tk()`. Maybe better put all GUI in function and run function when `gui == "1"`

Comment: in short, the answer is yes.

Answer (score -1):

```
root = Tk()
root.title('ATM v.keypad buttons //////dont acc work///////')
            
        

# creates the buttons adds no value tho

# size of button
gridlabel1 = Button(root, text='1', padx=50, pady=50)
gridlabel2 = Button(root, text='2', padx=50, pady=50)
gridlabel3 = Button(root, text='3', padx=50, pady=50)
gridlabel4 = Button(root, text='4', padx=50, pady=50)
gridlabel5 = Button(root, text='5', padx=50, pady=50)
gridlabel6 = Button(root, text='6', padx=50, pady=50)
gridlabel7 = Button(root, text='7', padx=50, pady=50)
gridlabel8 = Button(root, text='8', padx=50, pady=50)
gridlabel9 = Button(root, text='9', padx=50, pady=50)
gridlabel0 = Button(root, text='0', padx=50, pady=50)
cancelbutton = Button(root, text='cancel', padx=75, pady=50)
clearbutton = Button(root, text='clear', padx=75, pady=50)
enterbutton = Button(root, text='enter', padx=75, pady=50)
# prints the button at set location
gridlabel1.grid(row=0, column=0)
gridlabel2.grid(row=0, column=1)
gridlabel3.grid(row=0, column=2)
gridlabel4.grid(row=1, column=0)
gridlabel5.grid(row=1, column=1)
gridlabel6.grid(row=1, column=2)
gridlabel7.grid(row=2, column=0)
gridlabel8.grid(row=2, column=1)
gridlabel9.grid(row=2, column=2)
gridlabel0.grid(row=3, column=1)
cancelbutton.grid(row=0, column=4)
clearbutton.grid(row=1, column=4)
enterbutton.grid(row=2, column=4)
root.mainloop()
```

that was my example notice how I put `root.mainloop()` at the end
was indented because it was in a if statement

Comment: You could improve the quality of this answer by focusing on what was asked. For all we know, your case worked for you, but your answer does not address the _correctness_ of calling `root.mainloop` inside of the conditional